# Which action is triggered when a theme was modified?

Tags: plugin-development, actions, child-theme, theme-customizer

I want to intercept plugin changes, but no action hook listed in the [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) seems to do it. I tried `after_switch_theme` which is triggered only after changing from one theme to another, and `load_themes.php` which is triggered when entering the "Appearance" page with the list of currently installed plugins.

Which action will be triggered after configuring a theme in customizer?
Which action will be triggered when a file of a child theme is modified?
Which action will be triggered when a theme was updated to a newer version?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? There might be a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime changes are saved in the Customizer, there is a `customize_save_after` hook.

For theme updates, you can use the `upgrader_process_complete` hook - you pass it various arguments including `'type' => 'theme'`.

I don't think there are any WordPress-specific hooks for when files of a child theme are modified. This typically happens via FTP, rather than wp-admin, so it wouldn't have any hooks. You could possibly write something yourself to check the server's modified timestamp on all the theme files, but that might be fairly server-intensive to check frequently.